# Прерывание работы метода класса в Python

Tags: python, классы

Имеется вопрос по Python. Тема Классы, вывод десятичного счетчика, который может увеличивать или уменьшать свое значение на единицу в заданном диапазоне.
В качестве примера привожу код. В нем, достигнув максимального значения диапазона, если продолжать вызывать my_count.increase() будет каждый раз выводиться 'Out of range'. Возможно ли  сократить вывод строки до одного раза, несмотря на последующие вызовы метода? Заранее благодарен.

```
class Counter:
    current=0
    def __init__(self, start=None, end=None):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        
    def increase(self):
        if self.current < self.end:
            self.current += 1
            return self.current 
        else:
            return 'Out of range'

my_count=Counter(start=0, end=3)
print(my_count.increase())  # --> 1
print(my_count.increase())  # --> 2
print(my_count.increase())  # --> 3
print(my_count.increase())  # --> 'Out of range'
print(my_count.increase())  # --> 'Out of range'
print(my_count.increase())  # --> 'Out of range'
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, делят только сначала. После первого `.increase()` будет у каждого счетчика своя собственная переменная `self.current`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант вы можете вызвать ошибку `IndexError` и тогда программист, который работает с вашим классом будет вынужден отреагировать на выход за пределы листа.

```
def increase(self):
    if self.current < self.end:
        self.current += 1
        return self.current
    else:
        raise IndexError('list index out of range')
```

Результат:

```
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/****/Documents/Develop/Local/PycharmProjects/pythonProject12/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(my_count.increase())  # --> 'Out of range'
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/****/Documents/Develop/Local/PycharmProjects/pythonProject12/main.py", line 13, in increase
    raise IndexError('list index out of range')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Прерывание выполнения метода достигается использованием оператора `return` либо вызовом исключения `raise`.
Как вариант -  можно добавить дополнительное свойство в класс `out_of_range = False`, когда отрабатывает блок `else` значение свойства меняете на `True`, затем проверяете значения свойсва `out_of_range` если оно `False` выводите 'Out of range' если `True` то просто `return` либо просто ничего `pass`:

```
class Counter:
    out_of_range = False
    current=0
    def __init__(self, start=None, end=None):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        
    def increase(self):
        if self.current < self.end:
            self.current += 1
            return self.current 
        else:
            if(self.out_of_range):
                pass
            else:
                self.out_of_range = True
                return 'Out of range'

my_count=Counter(start=0, end=3)
```

Прошу заметить, что у вас в любом случае выполняется метод `print`, поэтому даже если ваш метод не возвращает ничего в консоль будет выводится `None`, можно еще вернуть '', но это все равно не полное ничего :) Либо вам нужен свой метод `print` который вообще не будет задействовать консоль при аргументе равном `None`.

Поэтому вам лучше принимать решение что и когда выводить в консоль в самом методе. В идеале - вызывать исключение, затем обрабатывать его и уже потом принимать решение о том какое сообщение выводить в консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Я что-то добавил в ваш код:

```
class Counter:
    current = 0
    def __init__(self, start=None, end=None):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.out_of_range = False                            # см. 1
        
    def increase(self):
        if self.end is None or self.current < self.end:      # см. 2
            self.current += 1
            return self.current 
        elif not self.out_of_range:                          # см. 3
            self.out_of_range = True                         # см. 4
            return 'Out of range'
        else:
            return ''                                        # см. 5
```

---

*Объяснения:*

1. Я добавил переменную объекта `out_of_range`, которая сначала будет иметь значение `False`.
2. В вашем коде *отсутствует обработка для `end=None`.* Здесь она добавлена.
3. Когда пока не было достигнуто максимального значения диапазона (т.е. это первый случай),
4. отметим, что только что оно достигнуто выло.
5. Иначе вернем *пустую строку*, чтобы функция `print()` уже ничего не печатала.

---

*Примечание:*

Для создания объекта не надо ключей. Вместо

```
my_count = Counter(start=0, end=3)
```

вы можете написать

```
my_count = Counter(0, 3)
```